# can not open FIFO

Tags: c, linux, ipc, named-pipes, mkfifo

I write this program to test the FIFO in Ubuntu。The main program create a child process to write something ,and then the parent read and print it

```
/*
   communication with named pipe(or FIFO)
   @author  myqiqiang
   @email   myqiqiang@gmail.com
*/
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#define FIFO_SERVER "/home/myqiqiang/fifoserver" //fifo directioy
#define BUFFERSIZE 80
void main()
{
    pid_t pc;
    int flag,fd;
    char data[BUFFERSIZE+1];
    char* test="a test string";
    if(mkfifo(FIFO_SERVER,O_CREAT|O_EXCL)<0)    //create fifo
    {
        printf("create named pipe failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("create named pipe sucessfully\n");
    pc=fork();  //create process
    if(pc==0)
    {
        memset(data,0,strlen(test));
        fd=open(FIFO_SERVER,O_WRONLY,0);    //open the fifo
        if(fd==-1)  //if open failed
        {
            printf("write:cann't open the named pipe\n");
            unlink(FIFO_SERVER);
            exit(1);
        }
        flag=write(fd,test,13);     //write data
        if(flag==-1)    //write failed
        {
            printf("write data error\n");
            unlink(FIFO_SERVER);
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("write data successfully\n");
        close(fd);  //clsoe fifo
        unlink(FIFO_SERVER);    //delete fifo
    }
    else
        if(pc>0)
        {
            memset(data,0,strlen(test));
            fd=open(FIFO_SERVER,O_RDONLY,0);
            if(fd==-1)
            {
                printf("read:cann't open the named pipe\n");
                unlink(FIFO_SERVER);
                exit(1);
            }
            flag=read(fd,data,13);
            if(flag==-1)
            {
                printf("read data error\n");
                unlink(FIFO_SERVER);
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("the data is%s\n",data);
            close(fd);
            unlink(FIFO_SERVER);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("create process error!\n");
            unlink(FIFO_SERVER);
            exit(1);
        }
}
```

however，it shows this every time i execute,i am sure that the fifo has benn crated .

```
myqiqiang@ubuntu:~/code/ch03/experiment$ ./3
create named pipe sucessfully
read:cann't open the named pipe
write:cann't open the named pipe
```

Comment: Use `perror` when `mkfifo` or `open` fails. You want to know what is the `errno`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to [`mkfifo()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) should be a `chmod`-type mode (e.g. `0777`), not a combination of `O_` flags.

Your process is creating a pipe for which it doesn't have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Thank you,i solve the problem with your guide.
BTW,i write 
mkfifo(FIFO_SERVER,O_CREAT|O_EXCL)
in the guide of my book,i know that mkfifo accept two arguments,then how it work O_CREAT|O_EXCL and permission，is it (O_CREAT|O_EXCL|0777)？,or it means my book is totally wrong?
please forgive my english.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use mkfifo with S_IWUSR, S_IRUSR, S_IRGRP ,S_IROTH modes refer http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/mkfifo.html

```
if(mkfifo(FIFO_SERVER, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)<0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do mkfifo and run as normal user (not-root) your permissions are:

p-wx------   1 root     root        0 Nov 27 15:17 fifoserver

So you need to reading permissions, easiest way is to add it to mkfifo FLAGS:

if(mkfifo(FIFO_SERVER,O_CREAT|O_EXCL|S_IRWXU)<0)

It will create file you can read from:

prwx------   1 root     root        0 Nov 27 15:18 fifoserver

Answer (score 0):

The `fifo` is created but not getting open later so check the permission. you can specify permossion while creating a [fifo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkfifo.html).