# Can not open FIFO for any operations

Tags: c, mkfifo

I write the program and create FIFO. It was created, but I can not open it for any operations. I saw similar questions here [can not open FIFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100788/can-not-open-fifo) , but actually I didn't understand its answer, but I think I've got something with permissions too. Can somebody please explain what is going on?

```
if (mkfifo("myFifo", 777) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Impossible");    
    _exit(0);
}
int fifo;
fifo = open("myFifo", 777);
```

Comment: What is `str`? Please always provide [mcve].

Comment: Also read `open` manual, second argument should be something like `O_RDONLY`, etc...

Comment: 777 is not equal to -1, so the equivalent is `mkfifo("myFifo", 0)`. Check your parentheses.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès sorry, edited justn now

Comment: 777 should be 0777.

Comment: The mkfifo mode should more likely be 0664. You usually don't want it executable or world-writable.

Comment: `open("myFifo",O_RDONLY)`...

Comment: Note that `777 != 0777`. The former is 01411 (octal), which is `r----x--t`, which probably is not what you want. Also: The second argument to `open()` is NOT the create mode, but `flags`.